# Is it possible to launch a specific activity with only data payload FCM notification?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

Using `Firebase Cloud Function`, I sent automatically a notification when a user reply to another one. When the notification is sent, the user can open it and an activity showing the conversation should be displayed. If my using only data as payload like below, it is not possible to perform a click_action and open the corresponding activity. Defining my payload like this (and get data in onMessageReceived) does not work:

```
const payload = {
  data : {
    post : xxx,
    comment : xxx,
    from : xxx,
    to : xxxx,
    action_click : "open_activity_B"
  }
};
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want without adding notification?

Thanks for your help

**Edit:**

Some more informations to explain you why I'm doing this like that. I want to create a notification as below (in foreground & background):

[image]

I achieved that only by using the method I provided you but without the click_action. If i use notification payload, I cannot display large icon (avatar at the end of the notification).
Furthermore, in foreground my icon app is displayed in the notification but in background, I have a default icon...

My code below:

```
if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        post_id = remoteMessage.getData().get("post");
        comment_id = remoteMessage.getData().get("comment");
        originatorUid = remoteMessage.getData().get("originatorUid");
        image = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");

        if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running 
job */ true) {
            // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use 
Firebase Job Dispatcher.
            scheduleJob();
        } else {
            // Handle message within 10 seconds
            handleNow();
        }

    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        clickaction = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
        icon = remoteMessage.getNotification().getIcon();
    }
```

Then in onMessageReceived:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(clickaction);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("post_id", post_id);
    intent.putExtra("comment_id", comment_id);
    intent.putExtra("originatorUid", originatorUid);
    pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    String channelId = getString(R.string.app_name);
    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.myicon)
                    .setLargeIcon(image)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: What does not work with this payload ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [official documentaion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive):

> **Messages with both notification and data payload, both background and
>   foreground.** In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras
>   of the intent of your **launcher Activity**.

The launcher activity is specified in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file using category `LAUNCHER` as specified below:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You can change the default behaviour overriding and specify another activity.  In your [message notification data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support), add a new property named **`click_action`** with the value of an action string. Then give it an intent filter in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file that matches the action, like in the example below:

```
{
  "to": "tgFvOPQLccSe:EDE90N.........5Tg",
  "notification": {
    "title": "My Message",
    "body": "Hello Kmel!",
    "click_action": "com.example.MY_NEW_ACTIVITY"
  },
  "data": {
    "score": "111"
  }
}
```

Define the intent filter like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MyFcmNotificationActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.MY_NEW_ACTIVITY" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But remember, the data payload is not delivered to the activity when the message is received, is delivered when the user clicks on the notification.

Comment: Hello Alex, I edtited my question adding more informations. thx

Comment: I see but wthat's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that my notification is different (I mean appearance) in a foreground or background context.  In foreground context, the large icon displaying a user avatar is present but in background context, this is not the case and it is a basic notification.

Comment: I understand, but you can customize your notification accordingly to your needs. I cannot see the problem.

Comment: This is the problem :) With my code above, normally, in any context, my notification should be displayed accordingly to my needs and it is not the case. So, something goes wrong and I cannot put the finger on it...

Comment: You asked a question that sounds like this: `Is it possible to launch a specific activity with only data payload FCM notification?`. The way your notification is, or is not displayed is basically another issue. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.